# Azure pipeline error: Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

This is my azure-pipelines.yaml

```
trigger:
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use dotnet sdk 3.1'
  inputs:
    version: 3.1.x
    includePreviewVersions: false

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*'
```

At the PublishBuildArtifacts tesk it shows the error:

> ### [error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/a/**/*

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure pipeline error: Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'

That because there is a slight syntax error in your yaml file. You could use following dotnet build task:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

You could check the correct syntax by classic editor:

[image]

Or you could check the document [Build your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#build-your-project) and [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the help for the `PublishBuildArtifact` step:

> The folder or file path to publish. This can be a fully-qualified path or a path relative to the root of the repository. **Wildcards are not supported.** Variables are supported. Example: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

You're trying to wildcard the `pathToPushlish`.  Setting that to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` will grab the directory and all contents, preserving structure, which it looks like you want.

Comment: i' ve set `pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'` but it shows again: ##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.

Comment: @C1X have you found any solution for it?

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Answer (score 0):

James is correct, if you want to publish your artifacts to the build machine just use the built-in directory, you will use that path later for your deployment, by that time if you are not sure about the artifact name you can just use wildcard to retrieve the package, if there is only 1 package.

Comment: Hi there... this looks more like a comment to Jame's answer than an answer on its own. I suggest you move your comment there.